# Is there a way to get both sets of loot at the end of the mysterious car park?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm at the end of the multi-story car park located at the Milton General Hospital. There is a trap/decision where it transpires that I must pick one set of loot, while the other one is incinerated. Given the tricksy nature of the heavily booby-trapped car park, I was wondering if there's a secret method that allows you to get both sets of loot. For reference, I'm talking about this area:
[image]

There is a button on each side which opens the respective door, while the loot in the other room is destroyed by a flamethrower and a bomb.

Can I get all the loot?

Edit: I've found that the left-hand flamethrower trap can be disabled from the outside and the right-hand bomb can be shot without damaging the loot. However, Bethesda has craftily decided that the left-hand bomb cannot be shot from outside while the right hand-flamethrower cannot be disabled from the outside. Could this fact hold the secret?

Comment: I haven't been there yet, so just speculating from the picture. It looks like there are two buttons. I imagine one for each loot? Could you somehow get your companion to press one while you press the other?

Comment: @DCShannon I missed some important information in the first edition of my question - check the edited version for more clarity

Comment: I'm still curious if you could activate both at the same time. You say one of the bombs can go off without destroying the loot by shooting it. Can you set off the other one with some kind of explosive? Molotov, maybe?

Comment: @DCShannon You can activate both at the same time - but then the remaining traps go off and both sets of loot are destroyed. I gave the explosives idea a go, but the bomb appears to be indestructible.

Comment: Also, the left hand bomb cannot be disarmed, even from the inside. I'm pretty sure the same is true of the right-hand flamethrower

Comment: Well then I got nothing. Sounds interesting, though. I'll have to give it a try next time I play.

Comment: I'm guessing `TCL` doesn't count?

Comment: @Mazura No, I would only want to do it legit

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I thought I figured it out. I shot the bomb on the right and disabled the flamethrower on the left. Then I utilized my gamma gun to set off the bomb on the left you can't shoot. Everything was still there in each room. I opened the right room first since that flamethrower was still active and nothing set off in the left, but when I walked into the left cell, it's as if the trap went off.

I'd like to think I found a loophole, but Bethesda automatically corrects itself lol

Comment: If even going to this length wasn't enough, I think we can safely assume it's impossible. Thanks for your answer

Comment: I think this is correct. I was trying this the other day. I went to the other side of all the walls to see if anything could be done from there. Throwing a grenade into the room doesn't set the bomb off. I tried shooting the bomb, and noticed that the bullethole was in the wall later, not the bomb, like the bomb isn't really there.

Comment: The reason is that the only way to remove items from containers in games built using the Gamebryo/Creation engine is to utilize a script. The script likely triggers as soon as you open the door to the other room.

Comment: I tried grenade over the back, but also I tried a synth relay grenade. He relayed in the cell, but I couldn't pacify him. I was planning on getting him to pick the stuff up.  I give up.

Answer (score 3):

I have tried countless times trying to get all of the loot but every way I have tried ends in the other loot being incinerated. I believe there is no possible way to get both, which makes sense as it is, in a sense, trying to teach you that sometimes you will have to sacrifice something to get another thing.

Comment: I don't get why the -1?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. I've tried everything save breaking the game. You can't legitimately get into both cages without at least one of the items stashes getting destroyed

Comment: Do you know for absolute certain? There may be a way you haven't thought of.

Answer (score 1):

I, me, myself haven't found a way in to both. But if you can destroy one bomb and deactivate a flametrhower, there should be a way to get all the loot.
(I even tried to go on the backside of the room to get some extra loot, but it didn't work):

Comment: Yeah, it's like they teased the player by letting them deactivate one device from each cell. I probably wouldn't be searching this if you couldn't deactivate any. It's a tease which makes you believe there is  a way. :(

Answer (score 1):

i went in front of a cage then span around in my power armour while holding A and i got out and ended up inside the cell and got back out by fast traveling

Comment: You were able to get both sets of loot like this?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one way for pc users and that is to turn off the colisson control (tcl) and collect the loots. figured this out after getting the compressed data from the boston public library.

Answer (score 0):

If you exit your power armor right it will push you into the cage then just fast travel out and then go back and push the button for the one you have not looted I have done this on the xbox one with out a problem.

Answer (score -2):

You can't have both but, if you save in front of the cage you will be able to check in the first one to see what is in it. I try many times and its always the same in each. So if you don't like what is in the first, load back your game and take the other one.  (fairy tail finger)

Comment: if you better want a mini nuke ammo and four fusion core take that one in each box it have 2 item that they are just basic and few caps, in the other one you will find a around 2-3 stimpak 2 buffout that you can see with a med-x beside and in the drugs box that is variable but its not really interested so i suggest to take the one on your left fusion core and nuke are much more hard to find.. i hope that i help you to take a decision